# where to find Magento 2 API docs?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, rest-api, webapi

Finally I found out the magento 2 api endpoint for all products as below

```
rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20
```

but I need more detailed docs about api endpoints which I coudn't find out yet. Is there magento have detailed docs about REST API ?

Comment: Below links will help you

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/bk-rest.html 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/performing-searches.html

Answer (score 0):

> where to find Magento 2 API docs?

**Magento Commerce for B2B Generate a local REST API reference**

- The **REST** documentation on the **Magento devdocs** website is generated
  with [Swagger UI](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) using a schema derived from the latest build of
  Magento 2.
- However, the REST API documentation on devdocs is static in that
  the Magento Developers website is not running an instance of
  Magento, and there is no live data.

  `http://magento_host/swagger`
- By default, Magento returns documentation for resources available to
  anonymous users. If you specify a valid value in the `api_key` text box
  in the upper right corner, **Swagger** returns **documentation** for all the
  APIs the user has access to. To generate an API key, call the **POST**
  `/V1/integration/customer/token` or **POST** `/V1/integration/admin/token` as
  directed in Token-based authentication.
- The generated Swagger documentation provides the capability to test
  **REST API** requests. A user can enter a sample request, then press the
  `Try it out!` button, and Swagger returns information such as a curl
  command, a request URL, a response body, a response code, and the
  response header. The Try it out! button will not work unless a bearer
  **authorization** token has been specified.

  > https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

  [ base url: /index.php/rest/default , api version: 2.2 ]

**Updated**

```
domain.com/rest/all/schema?services=all
```

Comment: I tried (POST) `http://my-website.com/V1/integration/admin/token` but I just get my website home cms site back as response. What parameters do I have to send?